# PRU won't initialize for hcsr-04 ultrasonic sensor (Beaglebone black)

Tags: sensors, beagleboneblack, proximitysensor

In order to use the hcsr-04 ultrasonic sensor using BBB's PRU, I have tried this git :
https://github.com/HudsonWerks/Range-Sensor-PRU

I get the error "the PRU failed to open", when I try to start "rangepru".
Doing some research, I feel like that is because my PRU is not initialized and that I should do : "echo BB-BONE-PRU-01 > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.8/slots" to correct it.

But with the recent debian versions (4.x), the cape manager changed and I found the file "slots" at: 
/sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots ; BUT, there is no way to open, modify it : 
- using "nano" I get "slots.swp Permission denied" 
- and by typing the correct echo command (modified from the one above) : I get : "write error: No such file or directory"

Best regards,
Elrise

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a suitable device tree driver.

Try to follow the instructions on:

https://github.com/luigif/hcsr04

related to the compilation and installation of the driver.

If you have a proper development environment, executing  `make install` should do everything for you.